# I have two identical CSV files, but one cannot be read into Pandas DataFrame due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode

The title explains the main issue, but let me elaborate. Let's say I have two CSV files - `csv1` and `csv2`. They each look like this:

`csv1`:

[image]

and `csv2`:

[image]

The problem is that when I run `pd.read_csv('./csv1.csv')` it works fine, but when I run `pd.read_csv('./csv2.csv')` I get a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 73: invalid start byte
```

The difference between the two CSV files is that `csv2` is basically `csv1` but with the dates sorted in ascending order. The operations that I did to achieve that are:

```
csv2 = csv1.sort_values(by=['date'])

csv2.to_csv('./Data/csv_final.csv', index=False)
```

Does anybody know what the problem is? I've tried looking at other solutions and many people suggest to try specifying a different encoding scheme when running `pd.read_csv()` but I'm just curious as to what the problem may be caused by.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this ```pd.read_csv('./csv2.csv',encoding='windows-1252')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> many people suggest to try specifying a different encoding scheme when running pd.read_csv()

Yes, this is what you should do - after first figuring out what encoding scheme the CSV file uses. Since the default of `utf-8` didn't work, the suggested `windows-1252` is a good guess.

> but I'm just curious as to what the problem may be caused by.

It's caused by the fact that the CSV file is not encoded in the `utf-8` encoding that Pandas assumed by default, and so attempting to read it with that encoding doesn't work.

You should make sure you understand [Unicode and text encoding in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html). It is arguably also a good idea to specify an encoding explicitly when you make the `.to_csv` call in the first place.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the encoding scheme has changed? I've never encountered this problem before because as you said for Python 3.X the default scheme is UTF-8. I'm curious what caused it to change...

Answer (score 1):

The byte complained of is 0x80 which in the Windows 1252 encoding is the euro symbol.

```
>>> "€".encode("windows-1252")
b'\x80'
```

Supply `encoding="windows-1252"` as a keyword parameter to the `read_csv()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a csv using excel or other tool can produce encoding errors. You should check position 73 using a plain text editor to see if there is an uncommon character.